# How do i find and output all the words that appear only once?

Tags: java, string, algorithm

I have to find words that appear only once (no less, no more) and output them. Unfortunately, this is what i have so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Type in a sentence and click Enter:");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String sentence = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println(sentence);
        String a[] = sentence.split(" ");
        int n = 0; //n will be the variable for the amount of a word's appearances
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            if (a[i]) { //Here i kinda want to find out how many times a certain word appears
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I recommend using a dictionary. Have the key be the word, and the value be the number of times the word is found. If a key is new, it wont be in the Dictionary.keys() returned array. So for each word, check if it is in elements, if it isn't, add it with 1 being the value. otherwise just increment it. here is documentation for the dictionary class https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-util-dictionary-class-java/

Comment: @JamesE better use a Map. Even dictionary’s Javadoc says in bold: “this class is obsolete!”.

Comment: I strongly recommend splitting your code into functions. Each function should be focused on one task. For instance, input/output is one task; looking for unique words is another task. Have one function that finds the unique words, and another function that handles the `System.in` and the `System.out.println`. Don't mix the two.

Answer (score 3):

Try this.

```
static List<String> onlyOnce(String sentence) {
    return Arrays.stream(sentence.split(" "))
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))
        .entrySet().stream()
        .filter(e -> e.getValue() == 1)
        .map(Entry::getKey)
        .toList();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(onlyOnce("a b c d a c x y x"));
}
```

output:

```
[b, d, y]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit** (Thanks to @Pirate's comment)
In the `Set` way, instead of one `Set`, you will need two.

Use `Set<String>` which ensures that each entry appears only once. (However, entries are case-sensitive. So, you may want to convert them all to upper or lower case before inserting.) If you use this approach, the `for` loop in your code may look like this:

```
Set<String> onceWords = new HashSet<>();
Set<String> repeatedWords = new HashSet<>();

for( int i = 0; i < a.length; i++ ){
    /* If the word was already seen, add it to repeated list. */
    if( onceWords.contains( a[ i ] ) ) repeatedWords.add( a[ i ] );
    onceWords.add( a[ i ] );
}

/* Now, remove all the repeated words from the distinct list. */
onceWords.removeAll( repeatedWords );
    
System.out.println( onceWords );
```

Comment: He doen't need to find the distinct words, he wants to find the words that appear only once.

Comment: Agreed. Misunderstood the question. Thanks.